# show that $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> how do you show that $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous at any point of its domain?

I was thinking about taking the limit and show that it is equal to $0$ such as

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} (f(x) -f(x_0)) =0 $$

But, I can't figure out how to proceed

much appreciated

Comment: What is your definition of $\sin x$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: use that $$\sin(x)-\sin(x_0)=2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x_0}{2}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x_0}{2}\right)$$
and write the right Hand side in the form
$$(x-x_0)\cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x-x_0}{2}\right)}{\frac{x-x_0}{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\frac{x+x_0}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Right, but this just shows continuity at $x=0$ implies global continuity. Continuity at $0$ is true since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$, which has a geometric proof.

Comment: but $$x=x_0$$ isn't Zero in the General case

Comment: Is there a way to factor out $(x - x_0)$ ?

Comment: Simply multiply and divide by it...

Answer (score 1):

If you define $\sin(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$ you have that it's the uniform limit of continuous functions (on compact intervals, but around any point we can take a such a region) and thus continuous.

Comment: thx. any chance you could look at another question? I reedited it but no adequate answer.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358035/find-all-derivatives-of-fx-xn-1-x-where-n-is-a-positive-integer

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin (x+d)-\sin x=(\sin x \cos d+\cos x \sin d)-\sin x=$$ $$=(\sin x)(-1+\cos d)+\cos x \sin d=-2\sin x \sin^2(d/2)+\cos x \sin d.$$ So it suffices to prove that $\lim_{d\to 0}\sin d=0,$ because that implies  $\lim_{x\to 0}2\sin^2(d/2) =0$ and hence that $\lim_{d\to 0}\sin (x+d)-\sin x=0.$

The geometric definition of $\sin d$, for real $d$, immediately implies that $|\sin d|\leq |d|$ for all real $d.$