# "find all derivatives of $f(x)= x^{n-1} |x|$, where $n$ is a positive integer."

Tags: real-analysis

> Quoting "find all derivatives of $f(x)= x^{n-1} |x|$, where $n$ is a positive integer."

NEW EDIT:

- **Case 1: when $n=1$, $f(x) = |x|$**

If $x>0$, $f(x) =x$ and $f'(x)=1$

If $x<0$, $f(x) = -x$ and $f'(x)=-1$

If $x=0$: 
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=1 \neq \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=-1 $$
It follows that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

- **Case 2: when $n=2$, $f(x)= x |x|$**

If $x>0$, then $f(x) = x^2$ , $f'(x) = 2x$

If $x<0$, then $f(x) = - x^2$, $f'(x) = -2x$

If $x=0 $
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=0 = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=0 $$
It follows that $f'(0) =0$

- **General case when n>1, $f(x)= x^{n-1} |x|$**,

If $x>0$, $f(x) = x^n $ , $f'(x) =nx^{n-1}$

If $x<0$, $f(x)= - x^n$, $f'(x) = -nx^{n-1}$

If $x=0$:
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=0 = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x=0}=0 $$
It follows that $f'(0) =0$

.

Any input is much appreciated

Comment: Your reasoning for $x=0$ is faulty :)

Comment: @ZacharySelk thx for the input, I did a new edit, What do you think?

Comment: Apart from the typo ($x=0$), you should write out the difference quotients before claiming their limits are $0$ if it is homework. Otherwise, it looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are correct (aside from a few of what I suppose are typos), but your third presumption is extremely fallacious. Just because we have a function $f$ with
$$f(0)=0$$
it does not necessarily follow that
$$f'(0)=0$$
However, you were correct, but the *real reason* is because the limit as $x\to 0$ of $f'(x)$ is $0$. Basically, at $x=0$, $f(x)$ behaves exactly like
$$\pm x^n$$
Since at $x=0$, the absolute value has no effect, and the rate of change of this function at $x=0$ (for natural $n \gt 1$) is always $0$.

Other than that, looks good! Treating it as a piecewise function was a good idea.

**NOTE:** You may have misunderstood the question. By "find all derivatives", it may have meant for you to differentiate more than one time and find an iterated differentiation formula.

Comment: For $n=1$, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @user251257 to show that I have to take the limit on the left and right of 0 and show that they are different, therefore the limit when approaches 0 does not exists. am I correct?

Comment: @gegu it depends on what do you mean by limit on the left and right of $0$.

Comment: @user251257 Ah, good catch. :P

Comment: @user251257  I did a new edit. What do you think?

Comment: @Nilknarf I did a new edit , what do you think?